# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'False'

Tags: python, flask-mail

Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from punchstarter import manager
  File "/app/punchstarter/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    mail = Mail(app)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py",     line 539, in __init__
    self.state = self.init_app(app)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 566, in init_app
    state = self.init_mail(app.config, app.debug, app.testing)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 552, in init_mail
    int(config.get('MAIL_DEBUG', debug)),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'False'
```

from my `__init__.py` line 29:

```
mail = Mail(app)
```

I am running python and I think there is some trouble with the `flask_mail` configs, but I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: We need more code. But as far as I understand this traceback, there is something wrong with your configs.

Comment: From the trace, the parameter 'MAIL_DEBUG' is set to 'False' in the config file.  But it is expected to be integer.

Comment: Do you know what integer it should be? How do I find that out?

Comment: @NathanWindsor From the source code of Flask-Mail, it should be '0' for False and '1' for True.

Comment: In your config file, you probably have a line like `MAIL_DEBUG = 'False'`.  If you remove the quotes it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
app.debug = 0
```

This worked for me

```
mail = Mail()  
app.debug = 0  
mail.init_app(app)
```

Comment: Helped me. I have set the debug level as "DEBUG". Which is a string. Still wonder why it works in that way. Need to try keeping DEBUG and MAIL_DEBUG in the configs. May be it'll work.